# Where is the giant cpython switch case statement moved?

Tags: python, cpython

Not sure if it's off topic but don't know any better place to ask.
In `cpython` there was a very giant `switch` `case` statement for executing each opcode.
This switch case previously was placed in the `_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault` function.
Here is the [link](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Python/ceval.c#L745). The switch case statement starts [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Python/ceval.c#L1323).
This was a core part of cpython and everyone who was interested in cpython internals, would probably explore it in detail. Recently I was searching for it and I couldn't find it. In this version of [`_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.0a6/Python/ceval.c#L702) I can't find it. It's much shorter than the last one.
I even tried to find this switch statement by searching for opcodes in my IDE. But even that didn't helped find where it is.
Can anyone who is aware of latest cpython development changes help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's in [`Python/generated_cases.c.h`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.0a6/Python/generated_cases.c.h), which gets inserted into `_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault` with an [`#include "generated_cases.c.h"`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.0a6/Python/ceval.c#L853).

As you might guess from the name, `generated_cases.c.h` is generated code. You can see the code generator in [`Tools/cases_generator/generate_cases.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.0a6/Tools/cases_generator/generate_cases.py)

Comment: I know it's not a part of the question, but would know which PEP or PR are related to it? I think it's a huge change.

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/98831

Comment: Ugh, much more typing compared to previously googling `ceval.c`

Comment: @KellyBundy I actually searched for that both in google and the code base. I found the `generated_cases.c.h` in the code base by I didn't understand that it's a replace for the switch-case statement.

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi Just in case you misunderstood me: I wasn't criticizing you for not googling, I was just saying that I used to look up that code by googling that short name and complained that I now have to use a longer name.